# Is there a way to have WebStorm complete a whole line?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Is there a way to have WebStorm complete a whole line?

I'm not looking for anything smart, just something like vim's [i_CTRL-X_CTRL-L](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-X_CTRL-L)

This can come in handy for repetitive import statements on top of a file:
`import Rea` can be completed to `import React from 'react';` that shows multiple times in other files of a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [their documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/auto-completing-code.html), IntelliJ only supports the following Auto-Completing Code scenarios:

- [Basic code completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/basic-code-completion-completing-names-and-keywords.html) on ⌃Space.
- [Type completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/smart-type-code-completion-completing-code-based-on-type-information.html) on ⌃⇧Space.
- [Completing punctuation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/completing-punctuation.html) on ⏎.
- [Completing statements](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/completing-statements.html) with smart ⏎.
- [Completing paths](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/completing-path.html) in the [Select Path dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/select-path-dialog.html).
- [Expanding words](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/hippie-completion-cyclic-expanding-words.html) with ⌥/.
- [Negating expressions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/negating-expressions.html) with an exclamation mark.
- Various tips and tricks on using the [suggestion lists](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/using-suggestion-list.html) that appear on invoking code completion.